# Inverse of column values in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix called `mydf`. How do I get the inverse of columns A and C as shown in result?

mydf

```
A  B  C
2  2  2 
1  3  2
```

result

```
A    B   C
0.5  2   0.5
1    3   0.5
```

Comment: `mydf[,c("A","C")]<-1/mydf[,c("A","C")]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg That is right. Should be pretty simple, but only want for specific columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
mydf[c(1,3)] <- lapply(mydf[c(1,3)], function(x) 1/x)
mydf
#    A B   C
#1 0.5 2 0.5
#2 1.0 3 0.5
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
      mutate_each(funs(1/.), -one_of("B"))
```

NOTE: Here I am assuming the 'mydf' as `data.frame`

Comment: Specify that `mydf` must be a `data.frame` and cannot be a matrix. If you try this on a `matrix` (as OP said, despite the `mydf` name) things won't end well...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating a new data-frame, and then inverse the columns that need inversing

```
mydf <- data.frame(A=c(2,1), B=c(2,3), C=c(2,2))
mydf2 <- mydf
mydf2[,c(1,3)] <- mydf2[,c(1,3)]^(-1)
mydf2
#    A B   C
#1 0.5 2 0.5
#2 1.0 3 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works in R:

```
> df <- data.frame(A=c(2,4), B=c(2,5), C=c(2,2))
> df
#  A B C
#1 2 2 2
#2 4 5 2
> cols = c('A','B')
> df[cols] = 1/df[cols]
> df
#    A   B C
#1 0.50 0.5 2
#2 0.25 0.2 2
```